# Rcpp::DataFrame - find column type

Tags: r, rcpp

In all Rcpp examples that I could find, one must know the type of DataFrame columns, then you can extract column into vector, e.g.:

```
// construct the data.frame object
Rcpp::DataFrame DF = Rcpp::DataFrame(Dsexp);
// and access each column by name
Rcpp::IntegerVector a = DF["a"];
Rcpp::CharacterVector b = DF["b"];
Rcpp::DateVector c = DF["c"];
```

In R, one could find column types using `sapply()` function and `class` or `typeof`.

However, I couldn't find the external API in Rcpp responsible for type checking. Is there a way to find column type programmatically?

Comment: It seems you need to apply `TYPEOF()` and `R_data_class()` over each column; they return a `SEXPTYPE` and `SEXP (STRSXP)` respectively.

Comment: Can the downvoter explain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Dirk's comment, I found the solution in RcppGallery article:

[Dynamic Wrapping and Recursion with Rcpp](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/rcpp-wrap-and-recurse/)

`TYPEOF` and `Rf_isFactor` should be sufficient to determine the column types of DataFrame. `Rinternals.h` define the following types, which would be returned by `TYPEOF`:

```
#define INTSXP      13    /* integer vectors */
#define REALSXP     14    /* real variables */
#define CPLXSXP     15    /* complex variables */
#define STRSXP      16    /* string vectors */
#define DOTSXP      17    /* dot-dot-dot object */
#define ANYSXP      18    /* make "any" args work. */
#define VECSXP      19    /* generic vectors */
...
```

Comment: Yes, that is the best run-time trick we have.  But ... do you not know the structure of your data.frame beforehand?

Comment: Dirk - No I don't... any arbitrary data.frame could be passed from R to C++. Then I have to dynamically work with it - converting columns data to native C++ types, which can be now handled by my backend C++ functionality. All column types are acceptable by these C++ methods, so I have to know precise column types so I can treat them correctly.

Comment: Yes, accepting arbitrary data.frames is a little tricky indeed.

Answer (score 3):

You are not making a lot of sense to me.

Your example is on *names* of the columns, which is what works and what is documented.

But then you wish for a pony and selection on *type*.  Well, I have bad news for you: C++ generally does not have reflexivity. So we need to supply extra information.  For which we often use names.  Which gets us back to the previous case.

Trust me: it would be nice to do better. I am not sure I see how we can though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I didn't mean to stress out the use of column names at all. This example is there to show that I have to explicitly know the type of column `a` (integers) to correctly extract `IntegerVector`. Therefore it seems logical to me to have the ability to programmatically find/check the type of column `a` - hypothetically, something like this: `if(DF["a"].type == INT_TYPE)...`. Or like in R: `Rcpp::sapply(DF, class)`

Comment: We have some Rcpp Gallery posts which show how to switch on type.  You can't (easily) here though...